# Spring-boot: add application to tomcat server

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a back-end which is build on spring-boot and then some custom code from my school built upon that.
The front-end is pure angular application which I serve from a different server trough a gulp serve.
They're only connected by REST calls.

There's already an authentication module running on the backend and to now I need to serve this angular application from the same tomcat server the back-end is running on so it can also use this authentication module.

I've found [this about multiple connectors](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-tomcat) so I copied it as following class to set up multiple connectors:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class TomcatConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        //tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createSslConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector createSslConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        Http11NioProtocol protocol = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
        try {
            File keystore = new ClassPathResource("keystore").getFile();
            File truststore = new ClassPathResource("keystore").getFile();
            connector.setScheme("https");
            connector.setSecure(true);
            connector.setPort(8443);
            protocol.setSSLEnabled(true);
            protocol.setKeystoreFile(keystore.getAbsolutePath());
            protocol.setKeystorePass("changeit");
            protocol.setTruststoreFile(truststore.getAbsolutePath());
            protocol.setTruststorePass("changeit");
            protocol.setKeyAlias("apitester");
            return connector;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("can't access keystore: [" + "keystore"
                    + "] or truststore: [" + "keystore" + "]", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that I don't see or find how I should setup these connectors so they serve from my angularJS build folder.

Upon searching I came upon [Spring-Boot : How can I add tomcat connectors to bind to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111050/spring-boot-how-can-i-add-tomcat-connectors-to-bind-to-controller) but I'm not sure if in that solution I should change my current application or make a parent application for both applications.

My current application main looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"be.ugent.lca","be.ugent.sherpa.configuration"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
}
```

If possible I'd like some more info about what connectors are in the spring-boot context.
If this is not the way to go I'd like someone to be able to conform this second solution or suggest a change in my code.

I'm really not sure enough about these solution that I want to go breaking my application over it. (though it's backed up with github)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place your AngularJS + other front-end assets into `src/main/resources/static` folder, [Spring Boot will serve them automatically](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).

Comment: Thank you, this helped me forward in the right direction.
I've encountered some specific problems implementing this but I think it's better to open a new question for that.