# Multi-context spring-boot application: how to define standard spring-boot properties for each child context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There is good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111050/spring-boot-how-can-i-add-tomcat-connectors-to-bind-to-controller) about ability to add multiple tomcat connectors and bind them to separate controllers each.

The essense of Andy Wilkinson's good answer is here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder parentBuilder 
            = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ApplicationConfiguration.class);
    parentBuilder.child(ServiceOneConfiguration.class)
            .properties("server.port:8080").run(args);
    parentBuilder.child(ServiceTwoConfiguration.class)
            .properties("server.port:8081").run(args);      
}
```

I want to go on this futher and ask another question:

Is there a way to make each child application context to read some child specific application properties with support of all standard spring-boot's features, like profile-suffix file names etc.

## One hypothetical way to achieve it:

Have three separate property files:

- `application.properties`
- `child1.properties`
- `child2.properties`

And have ability to set one file for each context.

But what is important to me, that they must support all spring-boot magic. For example, if I activate new profile like passing command line argument `--spring.profiles.active=dev`, then automagically not only these three files should be loaded (one for each context), but another set of files (if they exist) also should be loaded automatically:

- `application-dev.properties`
- `child1-dev.properties`
- `child2-dev.properties`

Of course, these files should be searched at standard spring-boot's supported paths in defined order etc.

Is it possible out if the box of maybe with some coding?

## Another hypothetical way to achieve it

Have only one `application.properties` file (with support for profiles etc), but somehow to map prefixed properties to unprefixed properties of child contexts.

Example:

```
child1.server.port=8081
child1.foo=bar
child2.server.port=8082
child2.foo=baz
```

First child context should see these properties like if they were just:

```
server.port=8081
foo=bar
```

Second child context should see these properties like if they were just:

```
server.port=8082
foo=baz
```

So, standard spring-boot's autoconfigurations will work and correctly set tomcat's port etc.

---

I am not looking for specific approach (but if you ask me, I'm leaning towards second approach), but any working out-of-the-box or achievable with minimum conding apporach will suffice me.

Comment: In theory setting a value to `spring.config.name` of `application,child1` should do the trick. Else you can try passing it in as an argument into the `run` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve your first suggestion using `spring.config.name`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder parentBuilder =
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(ParentApplication.class)
                    .web(WebApplicationType.NONE);
    parentBuilder.run(args);
    parentBuilder.child(ServiceOneConfiguration.class)
            .properties("spring.config.name=child1").run(args);
    parentBuilder.child(ServiceTwoConfiguration.class)
            .properties("spring.config.name=child2").run(args);
}
```

You can then use `child1{-profile}.properties` and `child2{-profile}.properties` to configure service one and service two respectively.

For example, with `server.port=8081` in `child1.properties` and `server.port=8082` in `child2.properties`, you should see output similar to the following when starting an app that's using auto-configuration in the two child services and has a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web`:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

2019-01-22 13:38:09.690  INFO 80968 --- [           main] com.example.parent.ParentApplication     : Starting ParentApplication on …
2019-01-22 13:38:09.692  INFO 80968 --- [           main] com.example.parent.ParentApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-22 13:38:09.842  INFO 80968 --- [           main] com.example.parent.ParentApplication     : Started ParentApplication in 0.371 seconds (JVM running for 0.644)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

2019-01-22 13:38:10.046  INFO 80968 --- [           main] com.example.parent.ParentApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-22 13:38:10.584  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2019-01-22 13:38:10.604  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-01-22 13:38:10.605  INFO 80968 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
2019-01-22 13:38:10.613  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/awilkinson/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2019-01-22 13:38:10.668  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-01-22 13:38:10.668  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 612 ms
2019-01-22 13:38:10.829  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-01-22 13:38:10.981  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2019-01-22 13:38:10.981  INFO 80968 --- [           main] com.example.parent.ParentApplication     : Started ParentApplication in 0.955 seconds (JVM running for 1.784)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

2019-01-22 13:38:11.003  INFO 80968 --- [           main] com.example.parent.ParentApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-22 13:38:11.093  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8082 (http)
2019-01-22 13:38:11.095  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-01-22 13:38:11.096  INFO 80968 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
2019-01-22 13:38:11.100  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat-1].[localhost].[/]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-01-22 13:38:11.101  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 97 ms
2019-01-22 13:38:11.135  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-01-22 13:38:11.164  INFO 80968 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8082 (http) with context path ''
2019-01-22 13:38:11.165  INFO 80968 --- [           main] com.example.parent.ParentApplication     : Started ParentApplication in 0.183 seconds (JVM running for 1.967)
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy, it works. Just a clarification: I must do `parentBuilder.run(args);` before running child contexts to make it work (consider adding it to your answer). Also a side note: dev-tool's `ConditionEvaluationDeltaLoggingListener` is triggering and prints full "CONDITION EVALUATION DELTA" for some reason, when first child context started and before second child context starts. Maybe this is just a bug in dev-tools or something.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited to add `parentBuilder.run(args);`. The condition evaluation delta behaviour sounds like a bug. Please open an issue for it (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) if you'd like us to take a look.