# Spring Boot Actuator to run in separate thread pool

Tags: spring, spring-boot, threadpool, spring-boot-actuator

Is it possible to handle actuator requests like `health` within a separate thread pool from the "main" application?

Why am I asking? 
I've got an application that might sometimes use up all available threads, and the Kubernetes health check is failing due to the unavailability of a thread to compute the health endpoint request.

I want to make sure that every health request is processed no matter how much load the application is under.

I was thinking about maybe defining a separate thread pool for the actuators to operate with, but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: _"I want to make sure that every health request is processed no matter how much load the application is under."_ Does not this make your app unhealthy in the first place and it points to a deeper problem of threads utilization?

Comment: Also, what is the value of `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size` in your properties file?

Answer (score 5):

We had a similar problem with some of our apps when running in Kubernetes. We looked at different ways of creating [multiple tomcat connectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111050/spring-boot-how-can-i-add-tomcat-connectors-to-bind-to-controller) and [changing the spring management port](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-port) to get the desired affect, but never quite got it.

In the end, we attacked the root of the problem, which was resource starvation within the pod. We found that the apps experiencing the health check timeouts had lots of extra threads for various 3rd party thread pools. In some cases we had apps with close to 500 threads, so even under what we considered moderate load, the tomcat pools would get starved and couldn't handle new requests.

FWIW, the biggest culprit we found was the effect of [CPU request](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/) on a pod and the JDK. When we *didn't* set any request, the JDK would see every CPU on the *node* when it queried for numbers of processors. We found there are lots of places in the Java ecosystem where number of processors is used to initialize different thread pools.

In our case, each node had 36 processors, and we found around 10-12 thread pools using this number to determine size...not hard to see to how an app could quickly grow to 500 threads.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that switching to the nonblocking stack (Webflux) could solve your issue, should this be an option for you. If you rely on some blocking API (e.g. JDBC) you can publish it on a separate thread pool (e.g. Schedulers.elastic()). Thus, the HTTP request threads should always be available for processing the incoming trafic (including health check) and the long-running, blocking operations would be processed in a dedicated thread pool. I believe that similar effect should be possible using the asynchronous servlets API or anything that builds on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot >= 2.2, you can use the separate library [spring-boot-async-health-indicator](https://github.com/antoinemeyer/spring-boot-async-health-indicator/) to run your healthchecks on a separate thread pool.

Simply annotate your `HealthIndicator` with `@AsyncHealth`:

```
@AsyncHealth
@Component
public class AsynchronousHealthCheck implements HealthIndicator {

    @Override
    public Health health() { //will be executed on a separate thread pool
        actualCheck();
        return Health.up().build();
    }

}
```

*Disclaimer: I created this library for this exact purpose*

Comment: but dose this work when all workers are busy? the periodic health-check will be executed on a different thread. but the servlet not, or am i something missing here?

Comment: The thread pool has 10 threads max by default but can be configured to have more if you have lots of healthchecks that can take a long time. Your servlet lives in a different pool and will just return the last healths instantly.
Does this answer your question?

Comment: we have the problem that we dont get a health check when we have to much traffic, because all the servlets are busy, the reuest for the health check gets also delayed. Your solution will make the calculation of the health check Independent but the serving of the pre calculated health information will still use the same (in our case blocked by busy-workers) servlets.

Comment: That is correct. If you web server cannot serve requests at all, this won't change anything.