# Spring Boot App with Spring Security and HTTPS Enabled, not Possible to Expose HTTP URL endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, prometheus

I am having an issue with my Spring Boot app in which I've implemented Spring Security with custom login page and verification system. The whole app runs on HTTPS but I want to expose a certain URL on HTTP in order to Prometheus gets metrics from. I want to avoid in getting Prometheus TLS support.

I 've tried the following tutorials:

1. [How to Enable HTTP and HTTPS in Spring Boot](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/how-to-enable-http-https-in-spring-boot/)
2. [How set up Spring Boot to run HTTPS / HTTP ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896234/how-set-up-spring-boot-to-run-https-http-ports)
3. [Monitoring and management over HTTP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-management-specific-ssl)

But I am having the following stack trace when I am writing http://localhost:8081/greeting on my browser which corrensponds to a method (written below). The https://localhost:8443/greeting works just fine. Possibly this happens since I am calling the method from a HTTPS environment but I don't know what to change in security config class (presuming that is where I should start from).

Any advices? Thank you...

```
2022-10-07 17:21:01.190  INFO 14776 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x020x000x010x000x010xfc0x030x030xedv0x87l0xf9G0xb80xf10xae}0xd00x130x1e0xe10x0az0x810xc50xee0xd220xb10xf10xb2O%k0x92Ipd0x95 ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:271) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

**Security Config Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.authentication.security;

import com.andrekreou.iot.authentication.user.ApplicationUserService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .requiresChannel()
                    .antMatchers("/greeting")
                    .requiresInsecure()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v*/registration/**","/register*","/login","/registration","/registration-complete","/greeting").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID","Idea-2e8e7cee")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot;

import io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class IotApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IotApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new TimedAspect(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createStandardConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector createStandardConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setPort(httpPort);
        return connector;
    }

    @Value("${server.http.port}")
    private int httpPort;
}
```

**Application.properties**

```
#Server properties for HTTPS configuration
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:local-ssl.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=Puredrummer1
server.ssl.key-password=Puredrummer1
server.servlet.context-path=/
server.ssl.key-alias=local_ssl
server.port=8443
server.http.port=8081
```

**Rest Controller Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.control.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Sample {

    @GetMapping(value = "/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
        return "I am working with both HTTP and HTTPS";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Changed the code of Security Config Class and although the error hasn't gone I am getting redirection from 8443 to 8080, as I think it should.

Answer (score 0):

This exception can occur when you try to execute https request from on endpoint which isn't https enabled. It will encrypt request data when server is expecting raw data.

Change https:// to http:// for that endpoint manually which is designed to take http requests.

Comment: I am trying to implement HTTP and HTTPS simutaneously. The method I wrote above works just fine on "https: //localhost:8443/greeting" but not on "http: //localhost:8081/greeting". With that implementation what should I change besides your proposal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36853652/19476294

Comment: Refer to the above answer . I hope this will sort what  you are trying to acheive

Comment: I've already mentioned that answer in my initial question. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.